# How to access a specific version of a component?

Tags: python, sonarqube, sonarqube-api

I would like to get the measures of different versions of a component in SonarQube.

How can I access an older version than the one of the latest analysis with Python?

Comment: Could you please give us the version of SonarQube ?

Comment: It is Version 5.6.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting Sonarqube 6.3, you'll be able to use [api/measures/search_history](https://sonarcloud.io/web_api/api/measures/search_history).

Before that, you need to use api/timemachine/index.